# How to rollback iPad OS 3.2.2 to 3.2

Tags: ios, ipad

How to rollback iPad OS 3.2.2 to 3.2 for development purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downgraded from iOS4 to iOS3.1.2 on my iPhone 3G and iPod Touch, by downloading the OS off the internet and pressing alt (or it might have been Shift) while clicking the upgrade or restore button (in iTunes) and then in the open File Dialog which follows browsing to the downloaded Firmware.

Apple blocked me from restoring to 3.1.3 though.

I doubt this illegal as it's built into iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

There is not supported way to do this.  It might be possible using Jailbreak tools, but I'm not familiar with them.

I had the same issue.  I was using my iPod Touch as a 4.0 beta device, but now that 4.0 is gold and I put it on my 3GS, I wanted to use the iPod as a 3.1.3 compatibility test device.  Once Apple removes support for a specific version, iTunes and XCode will no longer let you install or update to an outdated version.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I am trying to download the new version of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. But not exactly for the reason Chris specifies -- if it were just down to Xcode or iTunes, one could always keep old installers around and just use those to do rollbacks. The real reason is the device doesn't allow itself to take an older version of firmware than what it already has.

This is a "gotcha" that seems to get every developer at least once. Consider it a rite of iOS development passage. :)